# can't get variable value in the if statement in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a simple batch file which will control access to the computer (using shutdown) so for every 30 minutes when the computer is on, there has to be at least 30 minutes when the computer is off. The file will be put in auto start. The algorithm looks as follows:

```
Get from the file time when the computer was last closed (LASTCLOSETIME)
calculate BREAKUNTIL as LASTCLOSETIME + 30 minutes
if CURRENTTIME < BREAKUNTIL {
    then shutdown now
} else {
    shutdown in 30 minutes
    save to the file CURRENTTIME + 30 minutes
}
```

I did not handle what happens in the first run if the file does not exist, but it is not a problem for now - a file exists and contains valid data.

The code I have:

```
::echo off

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%G IN ('TIME /T') DO SET CURRENTTIME=%%G
echo %CURRENTTIME%

set /A CURRENTTIME = %CURRENTTIME:~0,2%*60 + %CURRENTTIME:~3,2%
echo %CURRENTTIME%

set /P LASTCLOSETIME=<lastclose.txt

set /A BREAKUNTIL = %LASTCLOSETIME% + 30
set /A BREAKUNTIL = %BREAKUNTIL% %% 1440

echo CURRENTTIME: %CURRENTTIME%
echo LASTCLOSETIME: %LASTCLOSETIME%
echo BREAKUNTIL: %BREAKUNTIL%

if "%CURRENTTIME%" LSS "%BREAKUNTIL%" (
    shutdown -s -t 30
) else (
    shutdown -s -t 1800

    set CLOSETIME = %CURRENTTIME%
    echo CLOSETIME: %CLOSETIME%
    set /A CLOSETIME = %CLOSETIME% + 30
    set /A CLOSETIME = %CLOSETIME% %% 1440

    echo %CLOSETIME%
    echo %CLOSETIME% > lastclose.txt
)

PAUSE
```

The problem is where I set `CLOSETIME`. It successfully gets the value of `CURRENTTIME` and I can see e.g. `"set CLOSETIME = 886"` in the console but the next line does not print this time at all, as if a variable was not set. Does it have something to do with the if statement? I have tried using labels and goto statements but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard DELAYEDEXPANSION problem.

This is ONE compound statement:

```
if "%CURRENTTIME%" LSS "%BREAKUNTIL%" (
    shutdown -s -t 30
) else (
    shutdown -s -t 1800

    set CLOSETIME = %CURRENTTIME%
    echo CLOSETIME: %CLOSETIME%
    set /A CLOSETIME = %CLOSETIME% + 30
    set /A CLOSETIME = %CLOSETIME% %% 1440

    echo %CLOSETIME%
    echo %CLOSETIME% > lastclose.txt
)
```

When the statement is PARSED, the CURRENT values of any `%var%` are substituted and ***THEN*** the statement is executed. The value isn't ASSIGNED to `closetime` until the statement is EXECUTED, hence the statement is interpreted as

```
if "%CURRENTTIME%" LSS "%BREAKUNTIL%" (
    shutdown -s -t 30
) else (
    shutdown -s -t 1800

    set CLOSETIME = %CURRENTTIME%
    echo CLOSETIME: 
    set /A CLOSETIME = + 30
    set /A CLOSETIME =  %% 1440

    echo 
    echo  > lastclose.txt
)
```

Easiest cure is to change this sequence to

```
if "%CURRENTTIME%" LSS "%BREAKUNTIL%" (
    shutdown -s -t 30
    GOTO :EOF
)
shutdown -s -t 1800

set CLOSETIME = %CURRENTTIME%
echo CLOSETIME: %CLOSETIME%
set /A CLOSETIME = %CLOSETIME% + 30
set /A CLOSETIME = %CLOSETIME% %% 1440

echo %CLOSETIME%
echo %CLOSETIME% > lastclose.txt
```

Note that `GOTO :EOF` where the colon is `required` means 'go to the physical end-of-file.

Second easiest is to execute

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

somewhere before this `IF` statement (commonly directly after the `@echo off`) and change the `IF` to

```
if "%CURRENTTIME%" LSS "%BREAKUNTIL%" (
    shutdown -s -t 30
) else (
    shutdown -s -t 1800

    set CLOSETIME = %CURRENTTIME%
    echo CLOSETIME: !CLOSETIME!
    set /A CLOSETIME = !CLOSETIME! + 30
    set /A CLOSETIME = !CLOSETIME! %% 1440

    echo !CLOSETIME!
    echo !CLOSETIME! > lastclose.txt
)
```

Noting that when `DELAYEDEXPANSION` is in effect, `!var!` returns the RUNTIME value of `var` (ie as it changes) whereas `%var%` returns the PARSE-TIME value of `var` (ie as it stood when the statement was parsed, before execution.)

Comment: Thanks. It explains a lot. I must have done something wrong with goto and labels - I will try it again.

Comment: There is also one extra problem - there should be "set /A CLOSETIME = %CURRENTTIME%".

Comment: Hmm - yes. `SET /a` assigns the value of an arithmetic expression to a variable, and it's not sensitive to spaces. `SET var = expression` will set the variable `"var "` not `"var"` and both leading and trailing spaces will be included in the STRING value assigned. Hence the `/a` is required using the construct used. Quite right.