# Why does this Batch file INPUT not work within an IF statement?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64

If I run this batch file like this it fails within the IF loop. If I remove the IF loop (and the ending ")" it works as expected.
(t is never set to what you typed).

```
IF 1==1 (
set /p t=type in value
echo You typed: %t%
set t=%t% plus Suffix
echo Your value + suffix: %t%
)
pause
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't get variable value in the if statement in windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765884/cant-get-variable-value-in-the-if-statement-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

you need `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

IF 1==1 (
set /p "t=type in value: "
echo You typed: !t!
set "t=!t! plus Suffix"
echo Your value + suffix: !t!
)
pause
endlocal
exit/B
```

When the command processor finds a block (anything between parentheses), parses it completely and expand variables to the value they have when the block is evaluated. If you update a variable value within a block, you need to enable delayed expansion for the variable to reflect changes made. Also you must change `%var%` to `!var!`

Consider the following

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=Round 0"
echo( ----------------------------------------------
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  set "var=Round %%i"
  echo( var is %var% [not using delayed expansion]
  echo( var is !var! [using delayed expansion]
  echo( ---------------------------------------------- 
)
echo( After block %var% !var! are the same 
pause
exit/B
```